# roll a ball using CMMotionManager swift iOS sdk

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I am trying make an roll a ball application using `CMMotionManager`.
here is my code :

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var circleView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var accelX: UILabel!

    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    var circleCentre : CGPoint!
    var newCircleCentre : CGPoint!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01 //1.0 / 60.0

        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in
            if let myData = data
            {

                self.newCircleCentre.x = (CGFloat(myData.acceleration.x) * 10)
                self.newCircleCentre.y = (CGFloat(myData.acceleration.y) * 10)
                self.circleCentre = CGPoint(x: self.circleCentre.x + self.newCircleCentre.x, y: self.circleCentre.y + self.newCircleCentre.y)

                self.accelX.text = String(format: "X == %.2f  Y == %.2f", self.circleCentre.x, self.circleCentre.y)

                if self.circleCentre.x < 20 {
                    self.circleCentre = CGPoint(x: 20, y: self.circleCentre.y)
                }

                if self.circleCentre.x > 256 {
                    self.circleCentre = CGPoint(x: 256, y: self.circleCentre.y)
                }

                if self.circleCentre.y < 20 {
                    self.circleCentre = CGPoint(x: self.circleCentre.x, y: 20)
                }

                if self.circleCentre.y > 256 {
                    self.circleCentre = CGPoint(x: self.circleCentre.x, y: 256)
                }

                self.circleView.center = self.circleCentre

            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        circleCentre = self.circleView.center
        newCircleCentre = self.circleView.center
    }


}
```

but its not behaving proper ball is moving continuously and not stopping at centre when my device is kept on surface. can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

First there are a few facts you need to consider:

- Your surface is never completely straight
- Your surface is in constant movement (even if unnoticeably small)
- Your phone is not designed to have infinite precision when measuring orientation

If you put a ball on a table does it stay where it is or does it tend to roll a bit? The harder the surface and more perfect the ball the more roll you will have. In your simulation the surface is perfect and the ball is perfect. It means it has no friction and no reason to keep still.

But you can set a threshold so the ball will stop if force is relatively small on it. Consider the following:

```
import CoreMotion


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var circleView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 50.0, height: 50.0))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        self.view.addSubview(view)
        return view
    }()

    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    var circleCentre : CGPoint!
    var newCircleCentre : CGPoint!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01 //1.0 / 60.0

        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in
            if let myData = data
            {

                self.newCircleCentre.x = (CGFloat(myData.acceleration.x) * 10)
                self.newCircleCentre.y = (CGFloat(myData.acceleration.y) * -10)

                if abs(self.newCircleCentre.x) + abs(self.newCircleCentre.y) < 1.0 {
                    self.newCircleCentre = .zero
                }

                self.circleCentre = CGPoint(x: self.circleCentre.x + self.newCircleCentre.x, y: self.circleCentre.y + self.newCircleCentre.y)

                self.circleCentre.x = max(self.circleView.frame.size.width*0.5, min(self.circleCentre.x, self.view.bounds.width - self.circleView.frame.size.width*0.5))
                self.circleCentre.y = max(self.circleView.frame.size.height*0.5, min(self.circleCentre.y, self.view.bounds.height - self.circleView.frame.size.height*0.5))


                self.circleView.center = self.circleCentre

            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        circleCentre = self.circleView.center
        newCircleCentre = self.circleView.center
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks @Matic , your answer is really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved the desired output. thank you all

```
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0

    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in
        if let myData = data {

            let xG = CGFloat(myData.acceleration.x) * 100
            let yG = -CGFloat(myData.acceleration.y) * 100

            let xPos = grillageCenter.x + xG
            let yPos = grillageCenter.y + yG

            print("x pos === \(xPos)")
            print("y pos === \(yPos)")

            self.circleView.center = CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos)
        }
    }
```